# Is there any way to skip Sky Force 2014's intro?

Tags: android, sky-force-2014

I often reinstall Sky Force 2014. Is there any way to skip the intro when launching the game for the first time and directly synchronize with one's FB/G+ account?

Comment: you could probably Decompile the .APK file and either replace the video with a very short one or see if there is a config file with a generic setting like "Intro_Video = 1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from hacking the game, as panomosh points out.

There is no way to skipping the intro as far as I know.